# Cannot figure out why Tensorflow-GPU does not use my GPU and why it displays N instaed of Y as output

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, nvidia, ubuntu-18.04

```html
(tfenv) hobbes@hobbes-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~/tfenv$ python
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
/home/hobbes/tfenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
>>> with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
...     a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
...     b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
...     c = tf.matmul(a, b)
... 
>>> with tf.Session() as sess:
...     print (sess.run(c))
... 
2018-05-26 17:39:53.860779: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2018-05-26 17:39:53.946021: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:898] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2018-05-26 17:39:53.946434: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1356] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 960M major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.176
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 1.96GiB freeMemory: 1.66GiB
2018-05-26 17:39:53.946450: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-05-26 17:39:54.449040: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-05-26 17:39:54.449064: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:929]      0 
2018-05-26 17:39:54.449070: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N 
2018-05-26 17:39:54.449194: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1416 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 960M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.0)
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]]
```

Right so I have been at this for weeks and I truly exhausted and therefore have decided to seek out the help of someone, anyone, willing to explain to me why on Earth my output returns:
2018-05-26 17:39:54.449070: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N 
With N instead of Y.

Any help of any sort would be immensely appreciated, truly.

Here is my output when I type out nvidia-smi in my terminal on Ubuntu 18.04

```html
<pre><font color="#8AE234"><b>hobbes@hobbes-HP-Pavilion-Notebook</b></font>:<font color="#729FCF"><b>~</b></font>$ nvidia-smi
Sat May 26 18:23:59 2018       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 396.24                 Driver Version: 396.24                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 960M    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   55C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    267MiB /  2002MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1286      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            24MiB |
|    0      1464      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          48MiB |
|    0      1650      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           103MiB |
|    0      1820      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          87MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
<font color="#8AE234"><b>hobbes@hobbes-HP-Pavilion-Notebook</b></font>:<font color="#729FCF"><b>~</b></font>$ 

</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you probably did it but gotta ask if you really did install `tensorflow-gpu`. And if you correctly managed cuDNN libraries by appropriate versions.

Comment: No man, please do not be sorry, I am already very grateful that you took the time to pay attention to my question and have a think!
As for your question, yes, yes I did install tensroflow-gpu mate! Yes I installed CUDA 9.0 and cuDNN 7.05!
Is there perhaps more information you would like me to share with you and if so what specifically mate?

Comment: Can I ask why does that bother you? you're getting right ans. There are some specific cuda jargon compiler has to return. It's not something most people bother with. Your expectation were different eh?

Comment: If everything is running properly it is meant to output Y and not N! So why on Earth would seeing N not bother me. After all, when I run my convolutional neural network code it takes forever and is way, way slower than when it is run using CPU

Comment: To see if you GPU is actually being used, run the program, then type `watch -n 0.1 nvidia-smi` in a terminal and look at the GPU usage.